# Extremely slow play framework 2.3 request handling code

Tags: java, performance, playframework, playframework-2.0, netty

I'm facing extremely slow performance of methods:

```
HttpRequestDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived()
```

and

```
Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run()
```

This two methods use around half of the time of every transaction in the server. It happens under low troughtput and during high usage hours.

For example, at 1am with only me doing requests to the aplication I get graphs in new relic like these:

### [image: New relic metric]

In this transaction only those two methods consume 1 full second, even slower that access the database via hibernate! Once again, only one user in the application.

If the transaction is heavier it takes even more time:

[image: New relic 2]

In this case, this two methods consume 2.5 seconds average when my own code consumes 1.5 seconds giving a total of 4 seconds. I thougth at that moment that maybe this was only a misleading of new relic metric. Maybe newrelic was showing this methods names but it was really code written by me. So I decided to get a custom metric like this:

```
playController(){
//Start timer
//do the job
//stop the timer() and send metric to new relic
//return;
}
```

And the result was that my code was taking 1.5 seconds. So it is really play request handler who is consuming this time.

This behaivour is killing my app when having a high load. This two methods can consume up to 20 seconds when the throghput is around 500 request per minute (not really a high throughput!) but my code keeps steady at max 3 seconds.

I really don't think this is a thread problem, because it even happends when there's a single user, but it become really problematic when having many concurrent requests. I tried changing the number of threads for "synchronous apps" like documentation mention but I didn't get any performance change, it even got worse.

I am really concerned about this problem because there's a similar case in the mailing lists of play with more than two years and no answer!:

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/play-framework/159bzf7r9p/help-to-understand-newrelic-report-for-slow-transactions-2-1-4

There's even a question that is similar in StackOverflow but for play 2.1 without answer and no aparent activity:

[Slow transactions in NewRelic having Play Framework as backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675074/slow-transactions-in-newrelic-having-play-framework-as-backend)

Any ideas what can be causing this behavior?

Comment: Which version of the newrelic agent are you using? Also, the agent itself can add some overhead: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/java-agent-overhead/26870

Comment: Also, since you say you are using Hibernate, I can only assume you are doing block/sync access to the database. You should try to experiment with different configurations for your thread pools.

Comment: Hi @marcospereira. I'm using new relic 3.25.0. I don't think newrelic is the problem because I was experimenting really slow responses so I decided to implement new relic. In other words, new relic was implemented after the performance problems appered. About Hibernate, I'm almost sure this is not a database/ORM problem because I'm measuring the time with custom metrics (no the defaults provided by newrelic) and the services-daos-queries are executing really fast.

Comment: @marcospereira thanks for the help marcos. The problem was newrelic, not by an overhead but by a wrong metric recording. Like you mentioned the problem was database access but since newrelic reported that 10% of the transaction time was database access It mislead the team for a lot of time! We discovered the problem using many profilers, slow query logs and AppDynamics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after a month I finally can say this issue is solved. And the answer is that there's no issue at all. **New relic default instrumentation does not report correctly the time consumed by Play Framework 2 transactions** and I could even say by any async framework that runs over Netty.

To get to that conclusion I had to include some custom metrics to the most problematic transactions just to discover that my custom instrumentation uses way less time than the reported by new relic.

After that I tested in the client using firebug and the times reported match my custom metrics.

Just a week ago I discovered this post in newrelic forums:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/frameworks/disable-scala-netty-akka-play-2-instrumentation

And after disabling all the instrumentation for netty, akka and play with this lines in newrelic configuration file I finally started to get realistic times by the default instrumentation:

```
common: &default_settings

  class_transformer:
    # Disable all Akka instrumentations
    com.newrelic.instrumentation.akka-2.0:
      enabled: false
    com.newrelic.instrumentation.akka-2.1:
      enabled: false
    com.newrelic.instrumentation.akka-2.2:
      enabled: false

    # Disable all Netty instrumentations
    com.newrelic.instrumentation.netty-3.4:
      enabled: false
    com.newrelic.instrumentation.netty-3.8:
      enabled: false
    com.newrelic.instrumentation.netty-4.0.0:
      enabled: false
    com.newrelic.instrumentation.netty-4.0.8:
      enabled: false

    # Disable all Play 2 instrumentations
    com.newrelic.instrumentation.play-2.1:
      enabled: false
    com.newrelic.instrumentation.play-2.2:
      enabled: false
    com.newrelic.instrumentation.play-2.3:
      enabled: false
    # New in Release 3.22, the Play 2.4 instrumentation does not respect
    # the older play2_instrumentation configuration setting 
    com.newrelic.instrumentation.play-2.4:
      enabled: false

    # Disable all Scala-language instrumentations
    com.newrelic.instrumentation.scala-2.9.3:
      enabled: false
```

In newrelic documentations says:

> You may choose to disable some or all of this instrumentation if you
>   find that the metrics reported aren't valuable to you, or if the
>   instrumentation incurs more overhead than you would like. If you
>   selectively disable some of the instrumentation, some segments of
>   activity will not be reported and your total time will be understated.

But IMHO it should say:

> You may choose to disable ALL of this instrumentation if you want to
>   get realistic metrics.

Why this behavior? I can only guess that Play and Netty reuses some threads in a pool by many transactions and newrelic agent is not able to separate correctly which time is consumed by the database and by netty, duplicating and sometimes triplicating the real times consumed by the application.

This problem mislead my team (and the sponsors of the project) drastically. I don't fully blame Newrelic, this tool is helpful but this left me as a lesson to don't trust only in one tool.